# jQuery .attr not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a sample problem on jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Q9yHD/

I am trying to add a border to my table with code:

```
      $("#") + $id).find(".name").attr("border", "thick");
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the border attribute of a `<table>` remove the extra `)`, here:

```
$("#") + $id).find(".name").attr("border", "thick"); 
     ^
```

To make it this:

```
$("#" + $id).find(".name").attr("border", "10");
```

Or if you're after CSS styling, you should use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$("#" + $id).find(".name").css("border", "solid 10px #000");
```

Comment: $("#" + $id).find(".table1").css("border", "solid 10px #000"); , but it isnt working.

Comment: @t3ch - I'm not sure exactly what you're after, there's no `.table1` in your example though, is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Q9yHD/4/

Comment: Hi Nick, I am sorry its not updating any changes I am making to it. but this is where I added the class table1 var $addTable = function() {
    return $('<table class="table1"><tr><td class="name"></td></tr></table>');
}

Comment: @t3ch - In that case the object wth the ID *is* the table, `.find()` looks *inside* which you don't need, just remove it like this: `$("#" + $id).css("border", "solid 10px #000");` You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Q9yHD/8/

Comment: @t3ch - Welcome :) If it resolves your issue be sure to accept an answer to each of your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code.  If you want to add a border only to a td with a class of 'name' then why not put that in the CSS portion and when you create the table and the eventual

```
<td class="name">name</td>
```

That thick style will be applied to it?